# Cassandra - EQ relation doesn't work on timestamp primary key

Tags: cassandra

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE experiment(
    id uuid,
    country text,
    data text,
    insert_timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(insert_timestamp));
```

I insert data via

```
INSERT INTO experiment(id, country, data, insert_timestamp) VALUES (uuid(), 'my', 'the data', dateof(now()));
```

When I

```
SELECT * from experiment;
```

I get

```
 insert_timestamp         | country | data     | id
--------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------
 2016-03-03 03:04:36+0000 |      my | the data | e08cddd2-b93d-4e39-b0f3-82b813f83a87
```

But, if I `SELECT` via `insert_timestamp`

```
SELECT * from experiment WHERE insert_timestamp = '2016-03-03 03:04:36+0000';
```

I get empty result.

```
 insert_timestamp | country | data | id
------------------+---------+------+----

(0 rows)
```

Any idea why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

> A timestamp. Strings constant are allow to input timestamps as dates,
>   see Working with dates below for more information. Datestamps with
>   format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS are returned.

So when you query the data using `2016-03-03 03:04:36+0000` it is interpreted as `2016-03-03 03:04:36.0+0000` which might not be true when you inserted the data.
Hence it is returning 0 rows.
**Note:** The date format visible in cql shell is configured in [cqlshrc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html) file's UI section.

Also dateOf function is deprecated [Details](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#usingtimestamps). And based on your data model if there are multiple threads writing data at same time your data will get override.